# Custom Camera Filters In Android

Tags: android, image, image-processing, opengl-es, android-camera

I'm developing An Android Custom Camera App And I Want to Add Some Filters/Effects Just Like **RETRICA** Or Other Apps like that...(**IN LIVE PREVIEW**)
I've Searched Internet and this site many times And I found same questions But Actually I didn't get What should I do?

They Suggested **OPEN GL ES** but No Code!
How does RETRICA Do this? or CAMERA 360 ?

`ANY TUTORIAL?`

Answer (score 1):

From Android 2.0 onwards we can set different effects.
You can set/get programmatically using camera parameters.

For example:

```
Camera.Parameters par = camera.getParameters();
par.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters. EFFECT_SEPIA);
camera.setParameters(par);
```

You can also set white balance, zoom, etc.

Check here the documentation about Camera.Parameters
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html

Comment: Thank you for answer but I need to make custom filters just like retrica, camera360 etc. Not Default Filters

Comment: Hey...@Erik Minarini......do you have any Other method or code ...for params.setColorEffect();.......in my samsung galaxy On 5...i am getting an NullPointerException....6 Colors Effect is printed in Logcat...But i want Total 9 Effects....please help me if you know..Thanks...God bless you.